# Laravel 8 installation in subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress installtion on an apache server `/var/www/html/`.

Within this folder (WP root), I've created a subfolder `beta` and in this folder have a Laravel 8 installation.

Separately (on a root domain/subdomain), the Laravel installtion works fine, but in my case it doesn't.

The first issue was with the `public` folder of laravel which looked like `mywebsite.com/beta/public`. I've fixed this by creating an `.htaccess` file within the Laravel root folder (`/var/www/html/beta/.htaccess`):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

After this move, I can acess the Laravel app without public: `mywebsite.com/beta`.

Now, I have a problem with the assets because all of them were set relative to home directory (/). Ex. `<img src="/images/img.jpg">` + css mix files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

I've also updated the `APP_URL=https://mywebsite.com/beta` within the `.env` file, but this still doesn't work. Actualy by `doesn't work` I mean that the website is loaded correctly, but unstyled, which makes sense since in the console all the paths are trying to access the '/css/app.css', '/js/app.js' , 'fonts/font.ttf' , etc.

Comment: Try adding a base tag to the head section of your document `<base href="/beta/">`

Comment: I didn't know about that tag. However it doen't work I'm afraid. Also tried `<base href="{{ env('APP_URL') }}/">` as an absolute url, but the assets are still trying to access relative to the home dir. THank you for the hint anyway. I appreciate your help

Comment: Spindey , if your links are using a `/` in the beginning then you will need to change it manually. The base tag works only if the links are using a relative path.

Comment: Also you can use a rule to quick fix the file paths, `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.(css|js|ttf)$ /beta/$1.$2 [R,L]`

Comment: @AmitVerma `base href` works indeed for assets without `/` at the beggining.  The problem is that the {{ mix('css/app.css') }} still doesn't, but just for test I've tried to hardcode the path like a regular asset and it works like this. So actually we lose the power of `mix()`. Secondly, looks like Livewire (not sure if you know about it) also points to '/vendor/livewire.js' and this path is not editable, because it comes from a call `@livewireScripts`. Last thing, are the fonts path, which is also created by webpack. The RewriteRule should be a better way, but it doesn't do anything in my cas

Comment: Spidey , `RewriteRule` should work and it's the easiest solution for your problem. The reason why it's not working for you is because you are using it in `/beta/. htaccess` . It should be used in `/.htaccess ` (root) but  as you said, in  root directory you have `wp`  it can conflict with your WordPress if used there .

Comment: yes, you're perfectly right. However, I was thinking of a tricky solution: Laravel askes for `vendor`, `images` and `fonts` folder to be on the root directory where `wp` is also installed. So what if I'll copy these folders to the root directory too? I tried these, but the files in these directory are seen like they are part of `wp` .. and `wp` responds with `404`. Maybe some `htaccess` rules can be helpful to instruct `wp` to ignore those folders and their files inside so they can be used by Laravel app instead. What do you think? I don't know any other solution. Thanks for your implication